# Split readings data into multiple lines

Tags: notepad++, string-manipulation

I have a text file containing data about the correspondence of readings and characters in the following style (not actual data, but exactly the same style):

> yī 一伊依医
>
> yí 乁仪侇仪冝凒
>
> yǐ 乙以佁侜倚偯尻崺已
>
> yì 乂义

I need them in the following form:

> yī 一
>
> yī 伊
>
> yī 依
>
> yī 医
>
> yí 乁
>
> yí 仪
>
> yí 侇
>
> yí 仪
>
> yí 冝
>
> yí 凒
>
> yǐ 乙
>
> yǐ 以
>
> yǐ 佁
>
> yǐ 侜
>
> yǐ 倚
>
> yǐ 偯
>
> yǐ 尻
>
> yǐ 崺
>
> yǐ 已
>
> yì 乂
>
> yì 义

Basically, the line will have exactly one space, and the segment of the line after the space should be split into single characters, which should be all prefixed with the segment before space ('nnn ABCDE' should turn into five lines, 'nnn A', 'nnn B', 'nnn C', 'nnn D', 'nnn E').

I tried to figure out a regular expression solution or something based on the Notepad++ capabilites themselves, but was unable to.

Comment: Could you show your attempts?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to go.

###### You have to hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> as many times as needed.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^\pL+\h)(\pL)(\pL+)(\R)`
- Replace with: `$1$2$4$1$3$4`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(           # group 1
  ^           # beginning of line
    \pL+        # 1 or more letters
    \h          # horizontal space
)           # end group
(\pL)       # group 2, 1 letter
(\pL+)      # group 3, 1 or more letters
(\R)        # group 4, any kind of linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, the first letters and a space
$2          # content of group 2, first character after the space
$4          # content of group 4, linebreak
$1          # content of group 1, the first letters and a space
$3          # content of group 3, other characters
$4          # content of group 4, linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]